# Python 3D histogram

Tags: python, image, histogram

I have X, Y, Z data and I want to make a picture out of it where the colour represents the value of z (interval average value of Z).

So far I can make a colorfull 2D histogram using the X, Y data (the colour is the X, Y occurrency frequency)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=(10,10))
```

Is there a python function to do what I need at once?

[image: 2d histogram, the colour representas the frequency of X, Y values in the interval]

Answer (score 0):

My first stop for questions like this is the [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html). If you want to plot a function in x and y, you may want to check out pyplot.contour or pyplot.pcolormesh (this one has some funny business with wanting 'cell centered' values for the colors, so it may drop the last row/column of the data). You can also check out the mplot3d toolkit near the bottom of the gallery if you want a 3d representaiton.